# Inheritance and Slicing, making it the child type

Tags: python, oop, slice

I have some code to do slicing:

```
class UnlabelledDataset(Dataset):
    ...

    def __getitem__(self,sliceIndex):
        data = self.data[sliceIndex]
        if np.size(data) and not isinstance(sliceIndex, (int,long)):
            return UnlabelledDataset(data) #Create Sliced Object
        else:
            return data
```

I want to inherit from this class to add functionality.
Slicing from the child class, should return a object of the child type
with all fields intact. 
How do I do this?
If I don't override the `__getitem__`, (and basically reimplement what is in the parent class, except the line marked `#Create Sliced Object`). 
Then slicing will return a object of type `UnlabelledDataset`. 
If I override it, then I am implementing the same code twice.

I can envision a solution where I use a helper function (possibly with a closure (function) passed in to do the constructing)
but I'm hoping there is a more elegant way

**EDIT:**
To clarify, the child classes may have different constructor signatures, to the parent. 
Eg the child class might have extra parameters. 
For example the child class has a resolution parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the parent, in place of `UnlabelledDataset(data)`, use `self.__class__(data)`.  This should produce the correct answer in both classes.

As a minimalist example:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data = data

    def f(self, data):
        return self.__class__(data)

class B(A):
    pass
```

When tested on the ipython command line:

```
In [15]: a = A()
In [16]: a.f('aaa')
Out[16]: <__main__.A at 0x2e99610>
In [17]: b = B()
In [18]: b.f('bbb')
Out[18]: <__main__.B at 0x2e99790>
```

Thus, as desired, method `f` produces a new instance of `A` when from `a` and a new instance of `B` when called from `b`.

#### Example with each class having different constructor signatures

If class `A` and `B` have different constructors, then we can create a new method, `make_new`, that handles the difference:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, data, x):
        self.data = data
        self.x = x

    def make_new(self, myslice):
        return self.__class__(self.data[myslice], self.x)

    def f(self, myslice):
        return self.make_new(myslice)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, data, x, y):
        self.data = data
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def make_new(self, myslice):
        return self.__class__(self.data[myslice], self.x, self.y)
```

Comment: Won't work because the child class constructors are different.
(Will edit question to point this out)

Comment: @Oxinabox See revised answer.

Comment: Nice, this what almost what I had came up with on my own, but combing that with __class__ for ones that signitures had not changes is fantastic!